# A question about time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, astrophysics, time-dilation

So I have failed to understand something in time dilation. Motion is relative right? So how do you chose for which observer the time runs slower? For example, when an astronaut spends time in a rocket that moves close to the speed of light (relative to earth) when he comes back to earth, everyone aged more than he did. But why is that? Why wouldn't it be the other way, I mean relative to him earth moved at the same speed, that he did relative to earth...

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange. What you are asking about is commonly called the Twin Paradox.  It is the same basic question as yours, but using twins, one of whom travels into space and the other stays home.  Who ages???   You can do a google search on Twin Paradox and you will find numerous simplified videos that will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like the Twin Paradox, but it isn't really the that. It can be answered without apparent contradiction in Minkowski Space ($M^4$): the proper time of a word line is a Lorentz invariant, and it is given by:

$$\Delta\tau = \int\frac 1 c \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}}=\int\frac{dt}{\gamma(t)}$$

which you can evaluate in any frame and find that the traveling twin's is shorter.

Special relativity is self-consistent (no contradictions), and when evaluated in $M^4$, it has no apparent contradictions (aka: paradoxes).

Comment: I guess there is a solution... I'm just trying to understand how do you decide for which observer the time runs slower... If two clocks are moving away from each other, for both, their time runs faster than the other's, but still when they meet we see that one's time was slower than the other's. When the astronaut comes back to earth, they are the ones who aged more... Why wouldn't it be that the astronaut is the one who ages more? Earth moved away from him the same way he did relative to earth...

Answer (score -1):

motion is relative to a very very VERY small scale. In he 1960's hey tried to prove experiment for time dilation they synchronized two atomic clocks and put on stationary and one on a Boeing 747 and flew it around the world, there was a discrepancy in time albeit mere nanoseconds observed. Time is relative to speed/motion. It's not until you start approach sublight speed time dilation becomes more observed

Comment: What I asked, exactly, is why is it that time ran slower for the clock on the boing plane necessarily, relative to it, the clock on earth moved at the same speed the clock on the plane moved relative to it, so how do you decide for which clock time will run slower...?

Comment: Add the time relative to Observer and traveler will differ.....If the clocks are synced, you measure time on land vs. time on vehicle upon return. These predictions of the theory of relativity have been repeatedly confirmed by experiment, and they are of practical concern, for instance in the operation of satellites which orbit Earth at 17000 mph+